# iOS swift streaming app does not play music in background mode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, background-process

My app is running fine but as soon the screen safe is on or the doing something else on the iphone the stream stops. I activated the background modes "is playing audio" but it does not helps.

This is my ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let player: MPMoviePlayerViewController = MPMoviePlayerViewController(contentURL: NSURL(string: "http://url to my stream"))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        player.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = .Streaming
        self.presentViewController(player, animated: true, completion: nil)

        loadAddressURL()
    }

    func stop() {
        player.moviePlayer.stop()
    }
    @IBAction func Hitplay(sender: AnyObject) {
        player.moviePlayer.play()
    }

    @IBAction func Hitpause(sender: AnyObject) {
        player.moviePlayer.stop()
    }

    @IBOutlet var Nowplay: UIWebView!
    var URLPath = "http://url to on air now"

    func loadAddressURL() {
        let requestURL = NSURL (string:URLPath)
        let request = NSURLRequest (URL: requestURL!)
        Nowplay.loadRequest(request)
    }
}
```

and here is my info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-      1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
 <string>en</string>
 <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
 <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
 <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.product name.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
<string>????</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1</string>
<key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
<true/>
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
</array>
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>LaunchScreen</string>
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
<string>Main</string>
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>armv7</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
</array>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting the audio background mode is correct, but I think you also need to set the audio category for the audio session.

Try adding this to your app delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
var activeError: NSError? = nil
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: &activeError)

if let actError = activeError {
  NSLog("Error setting audio active: \(actError.code)")
}

var categoryError: NSError? = nil
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: &categoryError)

if let catError = categoryError {
  NSLog("Error setting audio category: \(catError.code)")
}
```

Comment: yes, thanks for your help it is working as it should!