# How can I add a MP3 background loop into a page build by Interface Builder?

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6, interface-builder

i am new to iOS/Xcode/Swift, need a solution for inserting an audio file into the background of a page, file will be playing while people reading the page.

Answer (score 0):

I’d advice you to take a look at: 
[AVAudioPlayer not playing audio in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24792783/avaudioplayer-not-playing-audio-in-swift)  for the how do I get a working audio player.
For the “in the background” part of your questions I’ve found [iOS swift streaming app does not play music in background mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27280041/ios-swift-streaming-app-does-not-play-music-in-background-mode)  after a minute of searching. I hope these 2 Questions can help you further

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, what i did was create the AVAudioPlayer in my AppDelegate, then create an AppDelegate instance, that way the AVAudioPlayer instance will be global, in my desired ViewController and in the viewWillAppear method i called the `[player play];` method if you want to pause the music when the view disappears, like when you move to another ViewController, just call the `[player pause];` method in the viewWillDisappear.

what your AppDelegate.h file should look like:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@import AVFoundation;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,     AVAudioPlayerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (retain,nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *myPlayer;
@property (retain, nonatomic) AVAudioSession *session;


@end
```

what your AppDelegate.m file should look like:

```
 (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
NSError *error;
session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient error:&error];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:kSongTitle ofType:kSongFormat];
NSURL *pathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
myPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:pathURL error:&error];
[myPlayer setNumberOfLoops:-1.0];//for infinite loops set the value to a negative number..
[myPlayer setVolume:0.7];//this value varies between 0 and 1..

return YES;
}
```

your AppDelegate instance in your desired ViewController's .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AppDelegate *appDelegate;
```

your viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear methods:

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
[appDelegate.myPlayer pause];

}
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[appDelegate.myPlayer play];

}
```

also if you want to handle interruptions, say like a phone call was received, just call the `[myPlayer pause];` in the `applicationWillResignActive` method in the AppDelegate.m file. To resume the audio just call the `[myPlayer prepareToPlay];` and `[myPlayer play];` in the `applicationDidBecomeActive` method in the AppDelegate.m file.

P.S: I am using Objective-C.